# Impossible to press extended "pagedown" with Keyboard lib?

Tags: python, keyboard

I'm using the Keyboard library `import keyboard` for python and ran into a problem.

```
keyboard.press_and_release("pagedown")
keyboard.press_and_release("page down") #or this one
```

These commands presses the [ 3 ] on the Numpad (that correspond to the "PageDown" too).

But I need it to press the one on the Extra/Extended Keys area.

By using a simple function I can see that they have different keys.

```
def print_event(e):
    print(f"Key: {e.name}, Code: {e.scan_code}")

keyboard.hook(print_event)

> Key: page down, Code: 81
> Key: 3, Code: 81
```

But I don't seem to find a way to press it using the key code.

There's this issue on Github, but I have no idea what is happening there:
https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/issues/618